# Can't get jQuery var to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am trying to get a jQuery var into PHP so I can use it with mysql. I have searched everywhere but nothing seemed to solve it.

I have the following jQuery code:

```
$('.eventRow').click(function(){

    var eventID = this.id;

    $.ajax(
        {
        url: "index.php",
        type: "POST",

        data: { phpEventId: eventID},
        success: function (result) {
                console.log('success');

        }
    });

    $('#hiddenBox').html(eventID);
    console.log(eventID);

});
```

If I run this, the ID is shown in both #hiddenBox and in the console.log. The console also says "Succes" from the Ajax.

I am trying to get it in the php file:

```
$value = $_POST['phpEventId'];

echo "<div class = 'showNumber'>"."Nummer: ".$value."</div>";
```

It just says: Nummer:

It also gives no error whatsoever.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: How do you know it just says "Nummer:" ? I can't see any log in your php file and you don't display result.

Comment: Because I am echoing it, and printing it also doesn't display anything.

Comment: And where and how do you look at what is echoed ? Console ? Firebug ? Inspector ?

Comment: The inspector. I echo it in the index.php in a div as shown above. The inspector only shows " Number: "

Comment: How strange...  Did you try with GET or just testing your php file by sending directly a POST request to it ? (using poster plugin for instance)

Comment: Yes i tried. But is does not work either. Btw this is not a form button function, just a click function on a table row.I don't know if thats a problem

Comment: No, since it's an Ajax call no form is needed. But if sending data directly doesn't work it's a problem with your php. Are you sure recovering with $_POST works for.you ?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 var eventID = $(this).attr('id');
```

Where this id comes from in your code ?

Comment: It's an ID I get with mysql. <tr class = 'eventRow' id=\"".$row['ID']."\"> This works as when I inspect the element the ID is corresponding to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Passing it as JSON often gets the results I'm looking for.  The server will interpret the JSON object as POST variables:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "index.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify({phpEventId: eventID}),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (result) {
       console.log(result);
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried it, but it still doesn't display the number. The console.log displays the whole HTML.